# Return different types of Object in kotlin

Tags: object, kotlin, return

I am working with a method which returns different types of objects, I have used the Any type return, but is there a better option to achieve this?
This is my method:

```
override fun getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Observable<Any> {
        return scribeProvider.getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext).map { navItem ->
            scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem)
        }.toObservable()
    }
```

After I am doing a casting of the returned object, using the when operator, and I am doing something like this:

```
 when (item) {
                            is NavItem -> {
                                if (parentItem.hasChildren) {
                                    parentItem.items?.add(item)
                                    recursiveItem = item
                                }
                            }
                            is Image -> {
                                if (parentItem.hasImages) {
                                    parentItem.image = Image(item.image, item.selectedImage)
                                    recursiveItem = parentItem
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

And my other doubt is how can I use this method and extract this type of object with another approach.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there something in common between your objects? Do they implement any specific interface? Where are you using the object after you return it, are you casting it to anything? What does toObservable() return?

Comment: The objects are not common, and yeah I am doing a casting with the objects after, using the when operator. I can receive an item or an Image in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a [co-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) type, like the `Either` data type found in many popular FP libraries, for Kotlin, Arrow-kt already [provide it](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/core/either/), but the same can be done using `sealed classes` too.

**Example (sealed class**)

```
sealed class Result {
    data class A(val value: Int) : Result()
    data class B(val value: String) : Result()
}

fun intOrString(number: Int): Result =
    if (number%2 == 0) Result.A(number)
    else Result.B("~$number~")

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    (1..10).map(::intOrString).forEach(::println)
}
```

**Output**

```
B(value=~1~)
A(value=2)
B(value=~3~)
A(value=4)
B(value=~5~)
A(value=6)
B(value=~7~)
A(value=8)
B(value=~9~)
A(value=10)
```

**Example (Either data type)**

```
fun intOrString(number: Int): Either<Int, String> =
    if (number%2 == 0) Left(number)
    else Right("~$number~")

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    (1..10).map(::intOrString).forEach(::println)
}
```

**Output**

```
Right(b=~1~)
Left(a=2)
Right(b=~3~)
Left(a=4)
Right(b=~5~)
Left(a=6)
Right(b=~7~)
Left(a=8)
Right(b=~9~)
Left(a=10)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, since I need to return an Uri or a String for an image :) Thanks Omar

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin introduce [Sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) which is exactly what you need here. In your example it may look like this:

```
sealed class NavItem {
    object Item : NavItem()
    data class Image(val image: String, val selectedImage: String) : NavItem()
}

...

override fun getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Observable<NavItem> { ... }

...

// I don't know what class declares getNavItemById function
navigation.getNavItemById(serviceContext).subscribe { item ->
    when (item) {
        is Item -> {
            if (parentItem.hasChildren) {
                parentItem.items?.add(item)
                recursiveItem = item
            }
        }
        is Image -> {
            if (parentItem.hasImages) {
                parentItem.image = Image(item.image, item.selectedImage)
                recursiveItem = parentItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sealed classes [may be used](https://medium.com/car2godevs/kotlin-adt-74472319962a) (in some degree) as [Algebraic Data Types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type) from functional programming languages. I mainly use them as enums, for model types (`ChatType`, `ConnectionStatus`), view states and network request results.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about making your function generic like this:

```
override fun <T: Any> getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext): Observable<T> {
    return scribeProvider.getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext).map { navItem ->
            scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem)
    }.toObservable()
}
```

but for your use-case it wouldn't make a difference. Using when to distinguish between different types is the correct way to go since `item` will be smart-casted appropriately for further usage.