# Idiomatic way to represent a value that can be two primitives?

Tags: kotlin

A JSON response from a server gives me a key that can under some circumstances be a `Boolean`, and under others a `Float`, and I cannot anticipate it.

I'm working with Kotlinx serialization. For me the easiest way would be to have my model data class contain an object that represent this "double" value.

Sample JSON responses (both are equally likely):

```json
{
"key":true
}
```

```json
{
"key":10.5
}
```

Kotlin data class:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    @SerialName("key")
    @Serializable(with = BarSerializer::class)
    val bar: Bar
)

// BarSerializer implementation omitted as it's not relevant
// it just checks if the value is a float or a bool, and instances a Bar object correctly
```

Note that I do need the custom serializer because the actual JSON is quite nested and complex.

Now, here's my actual question.

`Bar` represents a single value that can be either a float or a bool. But all the ways I can think of seem ugly. There's probably a better way to implement `Bar`. Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```kotlin
class Bar(
    value: Any
) {
    var bool: Boolean? = null
    var float: Float? = null
    
    init {
        if (value is Boolean)
            bool = value
        else if (value is Float)
            float = value
    }
}
```

So my thinking is that when I need to use the value, I check which one is null, and use the other one. It's works great, but feels kinda hacky. I'm still a Kotlin noob so I'm sure there a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: You seem to want an `Either` type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153989/5133585) (The question is different from yours, but the answer should help in this case too).

Comment: You definitely need to do some sort of check when using it, otherwise it's not going to be safe. But you can still make it more elegant by making it so that after you checked that it's a `Bool`, you know for sure it is a `Float`, and vice versa.